# what are the absolute values of $e^{-|x+1|}$?

Tags: inequality

Why are these the absolute 
I get $x>1$ for both but its $x<1$ for $x+1$ and  $x>1$ for $-x-1$
I'm confused.

Comment: Please edit for clarity.

Comment: "*What are the inequalities of $e^{-|x+1|}$*"?  Are you asking for what values of $x$ is $e^{-|x+1|}$ positive and for what values is negative?  For all values it is positive... Are you perhaps asking instead how to write $e^{-|x+1|}$ without the absolute value sign?  That would be $\begin{cases} e^{-(x+1)}&\text{if } x+1\geq 0\\ e^{x+1}&\text{if }x+1<0\end{cases}$

Comment: No idea what you mean by “what are the inequalities.”

Comment: Why are *what* inequalities?  You get $x >1 $ for what?  And what doe you mean "what are the inequalities of something"?  We have utterly no idea what you are asking.  None at all.

Comment: @JMoravitz YES ! this is it thank you so much!!!!

Comment: As an aside... it is a very routine thing to be able to rewrite it without absolute value signs... You see an absolute value somewhere, then you can say "oh, when the expression inside is positive I can just change the absolute value sign into parentheses without changing anything..." hence why when $x+1\geq 0$ we have $e^{-|x+1|}=e^{-(x+1)}$ and when what was inside is smaller we flip the sign and then change to parentheses...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're confused :) (I see now that @JMoravitz wrote exactly this in his comment. But I just wanted to put the answer here before more nonsense got written.)

When $x+1\ge 0$ — so when $x\ge -1$ — we have $e^{-(x+1)}$. And when $x+1<0$ — so when $x<-1$ — we have $e^{x+1}$.